# HTML, CSS - image inside image, how to do that?

Tags: html, css, image, css-position

I have this piece of HTML code:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <image src="image-inside-pic-png.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <image src="pic.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

The **pic.png** (300x300 px) is the main image. I would like to put the **image-inside-pic-png.png** (20x20 px) inside of it. When I apply **position: absolute;** on the small image, it works only momentarily.
If I change the size of either, it no longer works.

So my question is, how can I move the small image always in the big image - and this small image will be always **15px** from the top and **30px** from the right margin of the big image?

Thank you for help

Comment: sounds like you're using a background image, which should be set via CSS. Is `image-inside-pic-png.png` part of the content, or is it simply used for style?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without changing your markup this can be achieved e.g. using `display:inline-block` to the outermost div element (so it won't extend for 100% of the available width) and position `relative + absolute` for outermost div and thumbnail

see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cRqhT/3/
border and image size are defined for simplicity

Answer (score 13):

I think this should work:

HTML:

```
<div>
  <img src="image-inside-pic-png.png" alt="" class="inner-image"/>
  <img src="pic.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  position: relative;
}

.inner-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 30px;
}
```

Anyway, make sure you need to do this with HTML. Maybe it's better to simply edit the image with Photoshop or Gimp. Or maybe one image it's only for styling purpose, then you should use CSS.

Answer (score 0):

put both images in one div which uses position:relatvie, then apply position:absolute to images, and adjust the value as you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
 **html**

  <div class="images">
          <img src="./images/Rectangle.png" alt="bg"/>
          <img src="./images/lady.png" alt="lady" class="lady-image"/>
  </div>
   


**css**
      .images {
       position: relative;
       }

       .lady-image {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: When answering you should include a description of your code so that others can understand how it addresses the question as asked